# Why factor levels are not in order in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a column as time which has values from 0:00 to 23:00
I am trying to factorize it but something weird is happening. I'll show in the code below.

```
//first I get the set of values from 0:00 to 23:00 

pain <- head(train_data$time, 24)

//then I run the factor function:
fpain <- factor(pain, levels = 0:23)
```

It returns:

```
     [1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>

    Levels: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

If I run without specifying levels:

```
  fpain <- factor(pain)
```

I get following:

```
  [1] 0:00  1:00  2:00  3:00  4:00  5:00  6:00  7:00  8:00  9:00  10:00 11:00 12:00 13:00 14:00 15:00 16:00 17:00 18:00 19:00 20:00 

  [22] 21:00 22:00 23:00
 24 Levels: 0:00 1:00 10:00 11:00 12:00 13:00 14:00 15:00 16:00 17:00 18:00 19:00 2:00 20:00 21:00 22:00 23:00 3:00 4:00 ... 9:00
```

How is the level going from 0:00, 1:00 to 10:00 directly? Why is it coming as NA in when I specify levels?

This is the datetime data, how do I work with these? The date time is has count for every hour.

Comment: Add your code to the post.

Comment: the question body has been changed following the restrictions on posting image. Thanks for ur interest.

Comment: `levels = 0:23` gives `c(0,1,...23)` which does not match to `"0:00","1:00"..."23:00"`, so you get `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that factors are numbers, which they are not.

When you do:

```
fpain <- factor(pain, levels = 0:23)
```

you are specifying the factor order `(0, 1, 2, 3, ...)` but your values are NOT `0, 1, 2, ...` but `0:00, 1:00, 2:00, ...`, therefore R returns `NA`, as it cannot match the values to the levels that you specified.

When you do

```
 fpain <- factor(pain)
```

R correctly creates levels `0:00, 1:00, ...` and orders them **alphabetically**, so your factor is indeed ordered.

If you want to impose a non alphabetical order you should use

```
 fpain <- factor(pain, levels=paste0(0:23, ":00"))
```

---

**EDIT** following comment.

If you are pulling time from a string the best solution is to use a combination of `strftime` and `strptime` instead. This way you can also format your times as hh:mm (i.e. with a leading 0) which will make it unnecessary to reorder levels.

For instance:

```
str.to.time <- strptime("9/1/2012 10:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Results in this POSIX object:

```
"2012-01-09 10:00:00 GMT"
```

You can then extract time using

```
strftime(str.to.time, "%H:%M")
[1] "10:00"
```

Comment: Thanks @nico. It worked for this particular set of data which is a subset of the data I have. The data contains datetime as dd/mm/yyyy hh:00
When I used your solution, it introduced <NA> in some rows because I had done substring blanks come as the prefix. For example if date is 9/1/2012 10:00 then the substring(date, 11,16) works but if date is 10/1/2012 1:00 then it fails. Any idea on how I can separate time from date and factor it?

Comment: Great ! So we separate the hour part and no need to factor it as it isn't string. When I plot, I do get a nice graph ! Thanks.

Comment: @elysefaulkner note that it is still considered a string, it's just that having the leading "0" orders them correctly even using alphabetical order (i.e.: `01:00 < 02:00 < 05:00 < 10:00` while `1:00 < 10:00 < 2:00 < 5:00`)